# Including the variation within a sample when comparing between samples

Tags: standard-deviation, coefficient-of-variation

I want to include the variation within a sample when analysing the variation between samples.

Say I have sample A, B, C.

Sample A was analysed three times with the values: 2398, 2383, 2411
Sample B: 2530
Sample C: 2391

The SD of sample A is 14.0
The SD of sample A, B, C with the values  2398, 2530, 2391 is 78.3

How do I make sense of this? At what threshold value can I determine if a sample differ from one another? How do I include the variation within a sample when calculating the variation between samples?

Comment: You should first start by stating your objective. Are you trying to study differences in mean or variance?

Comment: Probably both, I have to find a good parameter to compare the samples be it mean or variance..

Comment: In that case test for each with a separate test, one for verifying if variances are the same, and the other if the means are the same.

Comment: Yeah, and how do I determine that? They will differ to some degree but at what point can I say that they differ or is that threshold arbitrarily set up as a hypothesis by myself?

Comment: There is no universal rule on determining the value of alpha. The only thing you can go on is if you have any criteria specified about the false positives or negatives that can be tolerated.

Comment: Probably you want to do Hypothesis Testing, but it's still not clear. What are the values you quote? Where does the quoted standard deviation come from?